# Demultiplexing analog fast signal for 2-axis piezo movement

Tags: relay, multiplexer, triac, piezo

I am driving a 2-axis stick-slip piezo stage. Currently, I have two controllers, one for each axis. However, I would like to know how can I reduce it to a single controller? I need a sort of a demultiplexer that would allow to pass-through the voltage to either axis (I don't need to move both axes at the same time).

The controller generates a specific signal to move the piezo with max ~50V.  I am using 3.3V electronics (Arduino Due), and have access to a 12V source. I've quickly checked for multiplexers/demultiplexers, but couldn't find one that works up to 50V while is driven by 3.3V (the standard digital output from the Due).

I am considering relays, just have to find out which ones I can drive with 3.3V. Perhaps there's a solution with a **triac**?

**Update**: The controller is the OEM version of [this one](https://www.mechonics.de/products/electronics/cf30/), which is not *just* an amplifier, but it actually generates a special waveform (the piezo is a stick-slip, and thus requires a certain profile to move the steps). It is not particularly big (i.e. around 3x5cm) but it does get expensive if you need to buy 3 to drive a 3-axis piezo stage.

The voltage does not drop below 0V. Sadly, I have no plot of it, but it basically increases rapidly from 0 to 50V and drops back to 0V for forward movement, and does the opposite for backwards, i.e. increases slowly to 50V, and then drops quickly to 0V, etc.

Comment: I assume that your controller is a module you bought from somewhere else, and it's relatively big and expensive?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit about the "specific signal to move the piezo"? Is that AC, relative to your arduino's 0V (i.e. swings below and above that), or does it swing between that 0V and 50V?

Comment: (By the way, I assume you're using something like this: https://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=1191)

Comment: I have added a bit more of information to the question in order to answer your comments.

Comment: _"The controller is the OEM version of this one"_ - "CF30... Operates up to **3 axes**" - I'm confused. If it does 3 axes why do you need 2 of them?

Comment: Because the OEM version only drives 1 axis. Couldn't find the spec sheet on the website, and linked to the most similar controller, based on voltage generated.